# How to access nested items in Algolia instantsearch.js

Tags: algolia

In Algolia, I have the following data structure
[image]

In my instantsearch.js template how do I reference File > ID?

This is the template I have, but anything that is nested comes back as blank.  Top-level items (such as Title) are returned fine.:

```
search.addWidget(
        instantsearch.widgets.infiniteHits({
            container: '#SearchServiceHitsContainer',
            templates: {
                empty: 'No results',
                item: '<li class="content-search-results-item highlight"> \
                        <a href="/Content/ViewContent?file={{{File.ID}}}" target="_blank" class="content-search-results-item-trigger track-event" download title="{{Title}}" data-item-action="Download File" data-item-id="{{{File.ID}}}" data-item-title="{{Title}}" data-user-id="' + userID + '"> \
                            <div class="image-container"> \
                                <img data-original="/Content/ViewContent?file={{{Thumbnail.ID}}}&log=false" class="lazy" /><br /> \
                            </div> \
                            <span class="content-search-results-item-title">{{Title}}</span> \
                        </a> \
                    </li>'
            },
            hitsPerPage: 10
        })
    );
```

Comment: This should definitely work by default, if not then maybe some attributes are not present inside the Algolia response? Check https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/searching/what-is-attributestoretrieve-and-unretrievableattributes/#faq-section

If it's still not working, can you create a small jsFiddle demonstrating a similar issue? Then we can work from there.

Comment: This was it.   "Attributes to retrieve" was configured with some attributes, but was missing these particular ones.

Comment: @vvo If you want to make it an "answer" I will give you some points.

Comment: Done, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe check if the index parameter "attributesToRetrieve" is configured in a way that disable some attributes from being retrieved when displaying your search with Algolia: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/javascript/parameters/attributesToRetrieve/